# WCF data sent to client is NULL

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a service setup to take data from a console application acting as a server... sends it through the service... and the client being a WCF application recieves the updated data. However when I debug in the client, data is NULL everytime.

The weird thing is the console says it successfuly sent the data through.

Not sure where to go next or what code to place here as there is quite a bit of code... and I've been told not to post so much before.

Any thoughts?

Cheers.

Comment: Please provide a coded sample of what you are working with so that we can help guide you in the right direction.. sounds like you are not instantiating something somewhere.. or that you have an exception and you are not trapping it so there fore it probably jumps out of the Method that was Invoked.. are you doing any proper error exception checking..?

Comment: Some code will likely help.  If you can't isolate the parts of the code most likely to contain the problem, you can at least upload a [pastie](http://pastie.org/)/[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) or two and link to them..

Comment: Sorry just got it... I added some new properties that I had forgot to set as DataMembers. My bad... thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to set the properties to DataMember's. Works now.